Importing a file from a different folder
I have the folder structure 
├── project-main 

└── assets 

└── player.py 


└── map.py 

How do I import map.py into player.py
I tried
from map import *, which didn't work
I also tried
from project-main.map import *, this didn't work either
I get ModuleNotFoundError: no module named 'map'
Could this be because my initial folder has a - ?

please edit your question and enclose your depiction of the folder structure in a code block such that it renders properly. For help how to do that check out the Editing Help.

see: In Python, how can I import from a grandparent folder with a relative path?

Yeah, its basically because of the hyphen. Python module names should follow standard naming conventions, which typically allow letters, numbers, and underscores, but not hyphens.
So just change project-main to project_main and try:
from map import * 

or
from project_main.map import * 

If you dont want to change the folder name, I think you should check out this post

Try adding a dot in front of map if the files are in the same folder (im not sure if they are because of the text formatting) from .map import *
